# Mountain Lion change php location

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion

After upgrading to Mountain Lion I used this one line bash script to install php 5.4 http://php-osx.liip.ch/

It installs 5.4 to /usr/local/php5

If i run which php I get /usr/bin/php

And running php -v returns 5.3.13

How do tell Mountain Lion to use the php in /usr/local/php5

Will I also have to change Apache htttpd.conf to use the new version of php?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) rather than upgrading the native versions. If something goes wrong, it's just a reinstall of the software rather than the OS.

Comment: I was running MAMP but had problems with xhprof so switched to using the native installations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the hard way, you just link to the new php file:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php53 && sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Change the php5 bin path according to the real php5 binary path since I have no idea where the correct binary is.

But I'd rather try to use just `php5` on the command line since this is probably using the PHP5.4 version because `/usr/local` is usually in the `$PATH` as well.

You see which paths are checked by just `echo $PATH` on your command line. You may just add something to that by using `export PATH=/usr/local/php5:$PATH` or similar. You can add that line to the `~/.bash_profile` file as well to store that for any later use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed to add /usr/local/php5 to my PATH so I put it in my .bash_profile

I then ran the sudo mv ... command

If I now run php -v from terminal I get -bash: /usr/bin/php: is a directory

If I look at phpinfo on localhost It shows it running 5.4.5

Comment: I am sorry, you have to link to the real php 5.4 binary which is somewhere below `/usr/local/php5` probably `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` or similar.